# Reinforcing 2x8 floor joist

Tags: joists, beam, post

My home was built in the late 50's with 2x8 floor joists. When my 130 lbs dog runs across the room, the floor bounces  slightly.  We are wanting to reinforce that area before adding a heavier dining table.   My plan is to add a double or triple 2x8 beam at two points 1/3 and 2/3 across the room below.  Running perpendicular to the existing joists. The span is just under 15'.  Is this feasible without having to add a post in the middle of each beam?

Comment: What is the span of the 2x8 floor joists now?  15 feet is kind of pushing 2x8s free span limits, so might not help with the bouncing.  Will there be a problem adding post/s?

Comment: Also about 15'.  The posts would be right in the middle of our exercise room on top of a rowing machine and treadmill.

Comment: 15 foot span should only require one beam.  You do have plus or minus a few(2 or 3) feet either way from exactly centre.  Rule of thumb for joists is one inch per foot, span tables might give 2x8s maybe about 12 feet span.  15 feet does give bouncy floors.

Comment: You should sister all the joists. Use a hydraulic jack and some lumber in the middle of the span to get them to 'crown' a little bit, then attach a sister that's as long as possible. *Running perpendicular to the existing joists* you lose 8" of headroom and likely start to violate code.

Comment: How widely spaced are the 15 ft spanning joists?

Comment: Following @Maxura, [IRC R305.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR305.1) requires at least 6'-4" of floor to ceiling height under a header. Sistering every other joist or every third joist and then adding solid blocking between joists could provide the stiffness too, while saving a buck.

Comment: do you have solid cross bridging between joists, open cross bridging or no cross bridging?   a quick sketch of the existing floor structure might help - 2x8 joists 15' clear spans 12" oc? which part of the room bounces ( just the middle span ? ).

Comment: Sistering the joists would require moving a bunch of ductwork, water pipes and electrical. Not an option.

Comment: Popham, I'm not worried about code. I can't even stand up in my garage because an I beam and parts of the garage because of ducting and pipes.

Comment: Codemonger, no cross bridging.  12" oc. It's hard to tell what's bouncing exactly.  The whole floor shakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beams aren't holding the floor up, they are just to make it stiffer, so no additional posts are needed.

Even just adding cross-blocking between the joists can work to stiffen a floor.